# com.zaxxer.hikari Thread starvation or clock leap detected

Tags: gradle, hikaricp

In my Kotlin project in

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(
            "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
            , "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.+"
            , "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
            , "com.zaxxer:HikariCP:3.1.0"
            , 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.2'
            , "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1"
            , "org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.18"
            , 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    )

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

In my Kotlin code:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement
import com.google.gson.JsonParser
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
import okhttp3.*
import okio.ByteString

lateinit var ds: HikariDataSource

val dbConfig = HikariConfig("hikari.conf")
ds = HikariDataSource(dbConfig)

 val insertQuery = createInsertQuery(responseJsonElement);
            if (!insertQuery.isEmpty()) {
                val connection = ds.connection
                val insert = connection.prepareCall(insertQuery)
                insert.execute()
                insert.close()
                connection.close()
            }
        }
```

The `com.zaxxer.hikari` work success.

But sometime in debug.log I get the next warning

```
2019-04-26 00:00:08,899 18780794 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=1m29s94ms58µs).

2019-04-26 00:00:08,902 18780797 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=3, active=0, idle=3, waiting=0)

2019-04-26 00:00:38,905 18810800 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=3, active=0, idle=3, waiting=0)
```

Is it normal?

Comment: Pls check this discussion in the Hikari repo: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/679. In summary, looks like it's not much of an issue, esp. since your delta is pretty small (delta=1m29s94ms58µ).